# How can you show a character trembling without telling the reader

Tags: creative-writing

I'm trying to write this scene where the character is trembling but it's unrealistically.

"My heart was pounding beneath my chest. I trembled and felt terrible pain as if someone had hit me in the stomach."

Comment: It seems as though you keep forgetting your login details. Ordinarily I'd suggest [contacting the moderators](https://writing.stackexchange.com/contact) to ask them to merge your accounts, but our only moderator is inactive, so I'm not sure there's any point.

Comment: @F1Krazy Looks like merging isn’t a mod power anymore. Account merges are handled by CMs [on owner request](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: In that case, R Brown, [use the contact form](https://writing.stackexchange.com/contact) and see if you can get the CMs to merge your accounts, I think you have three by now.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid outright describing the character as trembling, you could focus on how this **feels from the character's perspective** and how it **affects nearby objects**.

In all likelihood, the character's hands are shaking. Maybe their teeth chatter, or their knees keep knocking together. Anything jingly they happen to hold or wear (such as keys or bracelets) will make a noise. Any openly carried liquid is likely to slosh and spill over.

They'd definitely have **trouble with anything requiring fine motor skills** (such as picking up an object or unlocking a door). When walking close to objects, they're more likely to bump into things.

Alternatively (or in addition to that), the character could be trembling with such force that it affects their surroundings. If the floor is a bit unstable, this could cause nearby furniture to wobble.

You might also include other details depending on what causes the character to tremble. Excitement, fear, shock, or physical illness?